# Javascript Function not working in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My JavaScript function is working perfectly in Firefox but in Google-Chrome and other webkit browsers it is not working properly and giving the following error in the console,

> "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL 'x' from frame
>   with URL 'y'. Domains, protocols and ports must match."

Following is the function code:

```
function xyz() {
    if (mainFrame.location.href === "x" || mainFrame.location.href === "y") {
        console.log('no');
    } else {
        mainFrame.location.replace("y");
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? What type of thing is `mainFrame` exactly?

Comment: mainFrame is the name of a frame and x and y are the urls which I want to check if they are equal to the mainFrame location.

Comment: And they obviously violate the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Comment: The error message says all there is to say. it's a security policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access frames across domains as a security measure. Make sure that even the subdomains match. `domain.com` is different than `www.domain.com`